# Upgraded from Win 8 to 10, Missing Files

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

We **upgraded** (not clean install) several computers to win10 from either win8 or win7 recently. Every other computer had absolutely zero data loss, but in one computer we had two critical excel files and one word file simply disappear. They're unique to that PC so they aren't available elsewhere, and they forgot to back up any files or use some kind of version control, etc (yes I know, there's our problem..). We tried looking in Network/*user*, windows.old, recycling bin, and with search to no avail. Is there a really good method or third party tool that we can use with decent success to try and find, or restore those files?

Comment: If you selected "Wipe all files and Data" during the upgrade, there is a good possibility that all personal files have been deleted.

Comment: So all the other files that were present on the HDD with Win8 carried over except for three personal documents, which struck me as a freak accident. I was simply wondering if anyone with a similar case of data loss had a good solution for getting the files back.

Comment: If you open Excel, are you able to see any "recent" files? I'm not sure if that kind of data gets carried over or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a simple search for the Excel files (e.g. searching for *.xlsx, *.xls) on C drive?

Also, you can try looking in the usual temp locations:
http://office-recovery.com/excel.asp

Comment: I actually did have them do that and we didn't see the files in question. I'm afraid no one is terribly tech savvy working with these units, and I wont be 100% sure until tomorrow probably what they have, and haven't tried.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Recuva https://www.piriform.com/recuva
This should help narrow your search.
https://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/recuva-quick-start/quick-start-if-you-know-the-file-names

Saved me before.

Good luck.